# How to get nerw file ID after DriveApp moveTo

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var idRisultati = DriveApp.getFileById(ssNew.getId()).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(idCartellaEsame));
  
var ssNeww = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idRisultati.getId());
```

The "move to" operation works fine and the file appears in the desired folder, but IdRisultati contains only the name of the new file created. How can I obtain the new file Id?

Comment: `idRisultati` is undefined

Comment: I don't receive any "undefined" error, the variable idRisultati contains the name of the new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
const file = DriveApp.getFileById(ssNew.getId()).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(idCartellaEsame));
  
var ssNeww = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, it works. It makes a difference to declare the variable as a "const".